# Linkedin link to website showing "link error"

Tags: linkedin, wordpress

I am trying to link to a post on our website (bulletpitch.xyz) from Linkedin. However, when adding the link to a post, linkedin hsows "https://www.linkedin.com/redir/invalid-link-page?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbulletpitch%2exyz" Does anyone have any suggestions? We are hosting our webapp on a wordpress site on a digitalOcean droplet.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: We contacted linkedin and they resolved the issue! Did not seem to be any issue on our end.